# How can I read my text messages from another device?

Tags: applications, google-play-store, sms

I have been using my country's local network for quiet some time, this number is used for all my transaction and other otp authentication stuff, also i use this to track incoming text messages from different services that i have subscribed to.

This number is currently used in my nexus, however i have plans to travel to another country (long time) where i need the otp and auth stuff. The country where i would be travelling would not support this cell network or its too expensive to have it supported.

Essentially, is there a way I can read my Nexus 5x's messages remotely I.e. from another device?

Answer (score 0):

## Remote Control? Hmmmm.

**AIRDROID!**

- Airdroid is an app that allows relative remote control of a device, remotely.
- Install it on the 5x, and **make sure you create an account.** Y'all be needing it. Also, tap the menu, then settings, and disable the confirmation for lite mode **and** enable keep-awake*
- On the other device, go to and bookmark `web.airdroid.com` **DO NOT LOGIN YET!**
- Disconnect from WiFi on your 'other' device, and in the 5x too if you want. Then, login on your other device.
- If all goes well, it will connect to your phone, no issues! Just tap 'messaging' in the corner, and you are done!

*You may need to enable Developer options (Settings -> about phone tap build number 7 times, then back, then pick the new options) and pick stay awake while charging (tick it!) Also, Airdroid is battery consuming, so keep it on charge!

Comment: Additionally, if you use USB or root, you can see and control the Android screen on your PC

Comment: Developer options is not necessary only for reading messages

Comment: @MarkYisri Had not tested that. sometimes, the option to stay awake while charging is in there.